# MicroK8S pods have no connectivity

Tags: kubernetes, connectivity, microk8s

No pods in newly created MicroK8S cluster on my Ubuntu have any connectivity, including coredns:

```
  $ k logs -f coredns-64c6478b6c-4pdnj -n kube-system
...
E0429 07:44:07.522557 1 reflector.go:127] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:156:
Failed to watch *v1.Endpoints: failed to list *v1.Endpoints:
Get "https://10.152.183.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0":
dial tcp 10.152.183.1:443: i/o timeout
```

However:

```
  $ curl -k https://10.152.183.1
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "reason": "Unauthorized",
  "code": 401
}%
```

What am I doing wrong? Both ufw and iptables are off:

```
  $ systemctl is-active ufw || systemctl is-active iptables
inactive
inactive
```

All my other pods also appear to have no network connectivity, although connectivity on the host machine is completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

We faced with the same error after force power off of the microk8s Machine. We have tried to check iptables and coredns But no results.
I suppose the problem with the kube-API. Need to check API logs.